# Determinant of matrix defined by binomial coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-coefficients, determinant

Let $m,n$ be a positive integers and $A=(a_{ij})$ be $n\times n$ matrix defined by $a_{ij}=\binom{m+i}{j}$
(if $m+i<j ,\binom{m+i}{j}=0)$. Find det$A$.

I think det $A= \binom{m+n}{m}$,but I can't prove it.
How to prove (not using combinatorial approach) ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but this looks very similar to an older answered question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1084252/137524

Comment: This is a special case of the question linked by @Semiclassical (namely $D(m+1,1)$ in the notation of the answer there). Although it is not in full detail, the answer shows that $D(m+1,1)=({n+m \atop n})D(m,0)$, and the question describes how to use row operations to show $D(m,0)=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can use the Van der Monde identity

$$
\binom{m+I}{K}=\sum_{J=0}^I \binom{I}{J} \binom{m}{K-J} 
$$

Putting $i=I+1,j=J+1,k=K+1$ (we need to do this because matrix indices start
from $1$ not $0$) and using $\binom{m+i-1}{k-1}=\frac{k}{m+i}\binom{m+i}{k}$, the above identity becomes

$$
\binom{m+i}{k}=\sum_{j=1}^i (m+i)\binom{i-1}{j-1} \frac{1}{k}\binom{m}{k-j} 
$$

This identity tells us that $A=LU$ where $L=(l_{ij})$ is defined by  $l_{ij}=(m+i)\binom{i}{j}$ and $U=(u_{jk})$ is defined by $u_{jk}=\frac{1}{k}\binom{m}{k-j}$. Now $L$ is lower-triangular so $\det(L)=\prod_{t=1}^n l_{tt}=\frac{1}{n!}$. Similarly $U$ is upper-triangular so $\det(U)=\prod_{t=1}^n u_{tt}=(m+1)\ldots (m+n)$, qed.

I admit that this is cheating because the Van der Monde identity is rather combinatorial in nature, but the proof was so simple I couldn't resist. If you insist on a 100% non-combinatorial proof, you can prove the Van der Monde identity by induction.